# How do I remove underlines from html links?

Tags: html, css

How do I remove underlines from html links?

Comment: css `a text-decoration:none`

Comment: Try googling first before asking questions @SO.

Comment: well I googled alot but this is pretty much where it got me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is this in the CSS:

```
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While `text-decoration: none;` will do what you're asking, here is a snippet to remove other oddities, like persistent outlines.

```
a.nostylelink {
  outline: none !important;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  color: inherit;
}
a.nostylelink:active,
a.nostylelink:visited,
a.nostylelink:link {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  outline: none !important;
}
a.nostylelink:hover {
  text-decoration: none !important;
  outline: none !important;
}
```

to use it, just add the class `nostylelink` to an `<a>` tag, or like this;

`<a class="nostylelink" href=""></a>`